# Understanding Mean +/- 1.5 SD in QGIS Symbology

Tags: qgis, r

I'm trying to automate a process that is now being made in QGIS, but I'd like to "transfer" the same operations to an R (or other language) code.

What I have is NDVI images for a given region of interest and currently I use QGIS' "Symbology" tool to reclassify my dataset and divide the observed NDVI in 10 classes (0.0-0.1, 0.1-0.2,... , 0.9-1.0). I'm using the  Mean +/- 1.5 SD option. What kind of operation does this tool make?

I know we can choose between Min/Max and Mean+/- 1.5 SD, but how exactly does this work?

QGIS takes the Original Dataset and makes **something** that returns different values, but I'm failing when I try to write an R script to do the same: the results are never equal, because I think I'm not doing exactly what QGIS does. I'm sure I'm missing some important part during this process.

What's the something I highlighted above?

I seek an explanation like: "QGIS takes the raster, divide by a number, multiply by other, establish cutoffs, and does whatever it does to return the new 'reclassified' image. If you do the same in a coded-like script, the results will be pretty much the same".

Perhaps you know some method that does the same thing in R. I looked into raster and terra packages, but my search wasn't successful.

Comment: This can't be the answer, but SD is standard deviation.

Comment: yes. But how does qgis uses the standard deviation in this reclassification? Any clues?

Comment: Many times, you don't want to divide your entire range into equal pieces because of extreme values. Mean +/- 1.5SD means you're dividing 1.5 standard deviations from the mean into ranged categories and everything above +1.5 SD or below -1.5 SD will be your highest or lowest color